# How to pass a currentday() type date/datetime function as a filter to an API in python?

Tags: python, get, datetime-format, asp.net-web-api-filters

I need to download current day minus 1 data from https://retsapi.raprets.com/CIN/RESO/OData/ every day by passing a filter condition like "&$filter=ModificationTimestamp%20ge%20%272022-03-04T13%3A19%3A56Z%27". Instead of passing timestamp value like I did in the filter condition mentioned I want to pass a date/datetime function. I am using python to make get calls to the API.

How do I make the below code work?

```
import requests  
import json

from datetime import datetime

bearerAccessToken = '#####################'

now = datetime.now()

resourceUrl = "https://retsapi.raprets.com/CIN/RESO/OData/Property?Class=Residential&$filter=ModificationTimestamp{}".format(now)

r = requests.get(resourceUrl, headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ bearerAccessToken})

print(r.text)
```

Above code is failing with syntax error:

"error":{ "code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innererror":{ "message":"Syntax error at position 28 in 'ModificationTimestamp2022-08-01 15:58:03.154348'.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException","stacktrace":"

The correct syntax is "ModificationTimestamp%20ge%20%272022-03-04T13%3A19%3A56Z%27".

How do I convert the output of datetime.now() to match "%20ge%20%272022-03-04T13%3A19%3A56Z%27"?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to pass a function"? Please read [ask].

Comment: I want to filter data like: select * from table where update_timestamp = currentday()-1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: API needs authorization in order to make a get call which I cannot provide here.

Comment: ...what does anything you've shown above have to do with an SQL query? And I see that you've changed your question to "I want to pass a date/datetime function", but I still have no idea what you mean by that. Again, please read [ask].

Comment: I updated the question with my code for a better understanding. Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you want to pass the output of a date function, you could just use `.format()` to create the url string and pass the function in there.

```
def a_date_function():
    # code converting string values to appropiate ascii chars
    return desired_output

url = "https://retsapi.raprets.com/CIN/RESO/OData/&$filter=ModificationTimestamp{}".format(a_date_function())

api_output = requests.get(url)
```

And that should give you a full url string with the output from the date function tacked on to the end where the `{}` is.

Comment: Could you take a look at the code I provided in the original question and tell what's wrong with it?

Comment: Would love to, but without having access to the API I won't be able recreate it or to tell you unless you provide the error you're getting or the output vs what you expect it to look like.

Comment: Uploaded the error. Plz have a look.

Comment: Okay, I won't be of much help at this stage, but looking at the error we can assume that your output in `r` is not a json string. Basically that first, larger traceback error suggests that something went wrong somewhere in the json decoding process. We then see the second error that points to a failure in the `r.json()` line in your file.

I would run it, but instead of doing `r.json` just try `print(r)` and see what it looks like. My bet is you're getting a response from the API you don't want that can't be parsed to json.

Comment: "error":{
    "code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innererror":{
      "message":"Syntax error at position 28 in 'ModificationTimestamp2022-08-01 15:58:03.154348'.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException","stacktrace":"                                                                                             

The correct syntax is "ModificationTimestamp%20ge%20%272022-03-04T13%3A19%3A56Z%27".

I don't know what time format it is. How do I convert the output of datetime.now() to match "%20ge%20%272022-03-04T13%3A19%3A56Z%27"?